# How to use msxml with Visual Studio 2008 Express (no ATL classes) without becoming crazy?

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2008, msxml

It is not really a question because I have already found a solution. It took me a lot of time, that's why I want to explain it here.

Msxml is based on COM so it is not really easy to use in C++ even when you have helpful classes to deal with memory allocation issues. But writing a new XML parser would be much more difficult so I wanted to use msxml.

**The problem:**

I was able to find enough examples on the internet to use msxml with the help of `CComPtr` (smart pointer to avoid having to call Release() for each IXMLDOMNode manually), `CComBSTR` (to convert C++ strings to the COM format for strings) and `CComVariant`. This 3 helpful classes are ATL classes and need an `#include <atlbase.h>`.

Problem: Visual Studio 2008 Express (the free version) doesn't include ATL.

**Solution:**

Use `comutil.h` and `comdef.h`, which include some simple helper classes:

- `_bstr_t` replaces more or less `CComBSTR`
- `_variant_t` replaces more or less `CComVariant`
- `_com_ptr_t` replaces indirectly `CComPtr` through the use of `_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF`

**Small example:**

```
#include <msxml.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <comutil.h>

// Define some smart pointers for MSXML
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IXMLDOMDocument,     __uuidof(IXMLDOMDocument));     // IXMLDOMDocumentPtr
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IXMLDOMElement,      __uuidof(IXMLDOMElement));      // IXMLDOMElementPtr
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IXMLDOMNodeList,     __uuidof(IXMLDOMNodeList));     // IXMLDOMNodeListPtr
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap, __uuidof(IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap)); // IXMLDOMNamedNodeMapPtr
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IXMLDOMNode,         __uuidof(IXMLDOMNode));         // IXMLDOMNodePtr

void test_msxml()
{
    // This program will use COM
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    {
        // Create parser
        IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pXMLDoc;
        HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof (DOMDocument), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IXMLDOMDocument, (void**)&pXMLDoc);
        pXMLDoc->put_validateOnParse(VARIANT_FALSE);
        pXMLDoc->put_resolveExternals(VARIANT_FALSE);
        pXMLDoc->put_preserveWhiteSpace(VARIANT_FALSE);

        // Open file
        VARIANT_BOOL bLoadOk;
        std::wstring sfilename = L"testfile.xml";
        hr = pXMLDoc->load(_variant_t(sfilename.c_str()), &bLoadOk);

        // Search for node <testtag>
        IXMLDOMNodePtr pNode;
        hr = pXMLDoc->selectSingleNode(_bstr_t(L"testtag"), &pNode);

        // Read something
        _bstr_t bstrText;
        hr = pNode->get_text(bstrText.GetAddress());
        std::string sSomething = bstrText;
    }

    // I'm finished with COM
    // (Don't call before all IXMLDOMNodePtr are out of scope)
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Comment: VS2008 express doesn't include ATL? that sucks. >:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy I posted my question although I already had a solution because I got several alternative solutions. Thanks for all your answers.

Using another parser such as [eXpat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) or the maybe smaller (not so powerfull but enough for my needs) [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml) could actually be a good idea (and make it easier to port the program to another operating system).

Using an [`#import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28VS.80%29.aspx) directive, apparently a Microsoft specific extension to simplify the use of COM, is also interesting and brought me to the following web page [`MSXML in C++ but as elegant as in C#`](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/davids/archive/2008/12/24/msxml-in-c-but-as-elegant-as-in-c-part-3.aspx), which explain how to simplify the use of msxml as much as possible.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe try using the `#import` statement.

I've used it in a VS6 project I have hanging around, you do something like this (for illustrative purposes only; this worked for me but I don't claim to be error proof):

```
#import  "msxml6.dll"

  ...

MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr pdoc;
HRESULT hr = pdoc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60));
if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) return hr;

MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr pschema;
HRESULT hr = pschema.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60));
if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) return hr;

pschema->async=VARIANT_FALSE;
VARIANT_BOOL b;
b = pschema->loadXML(_bstr_t( /* your schema XML here */ ));

MSXML2::IXMLDOMSchemaCollection2Ptr pSchemaCache;
hr = pSchemaCache.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::XMLSchemaCache60));
if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) return hr;

_variant_t vp=pschema.GetInterfacePtr();
pSchemaCache->add(_bstr_t( /* your namespace here */ ),vp); 

pdoc->async=VARIANT_FALSE;
pdoc->schemas = pSchemaCache.GetInterfacePtr();
pdoc->validateOnParse=VARIANT_TRUE;
if (how == e_filename)
    b = pdoc->load(v);
else
    b = pdoc->loadXML(bxmldoc);

pXMLError = pdoc->parseError;
if (pXMLError->errorCode != 0)
    return E_FAIL; // an unhelpful return code, sigh....
```

Comment: #import is the great way to go, easy and very little code to write by yoourself

Comment: I hadn't heard about "#import" before now (With C++ I have spend more time under Unix than under Windows until now). Seems to be quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would to use another XML parser that is already done, [such as eXpat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/).  It avoids having to use ATL and the complexities of COM, and is way easier than implementing your own.  I suggest this only becasue you've stated that the reason you're looking at msxml is because you don't want to implement your own parser.

Comment: I already thought about using eXpat, but as msxml already was on the computer, I thought that using it could help making a smaller programm. But if I had known about COM difficulties before that, I might have used eXpat...

Answer (score 1):

You can use TinyXML. It is open source and more over platform independent.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't heard about this parser before. It could be an "light" alternative to eXpat (through I haven't checked how much resources eXpat needs).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some MSXML wrapper that would shield you form COM, such as [Arabica](http://sourceforge.net/projects/arabica/)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't really want to add a layer of indirection to use the XML parser.